# live555 H.264 trick play

Tags: h.264, live555

Anyone know if live555 RTSP server can correctly reverse play h264 video?

I made index file for video using native MPEG2TransportStreamIndexer by 
live555 and trying to reverse play with speed -1 or -2 but video freezes for many seconds, jumps to another frame and continue freezes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think mpeg2ts support reverse play. And it's just a transport layer. Contained media stream should support reverse play. MJPEG will be most simple media format can be played forward / backward.